# Missing key in i18next translation

Tags: javascript, i18next

I am using http://i18next.com/ for multi-language support in my Javascript app.

However, I am running into an issue where, presumably, the Javascript that renders HTML is loaded before the file i18next uses to find translations, and instead of the translation text, I get an error.

For example, for a key-translation pair of "popups.notifications":"Account Notifications" I'll get:

```
i18next::translator: missingKey undefined translation popups.notifications popups.notifications
```

The i18next JS is included in the page header before any other Javascript, but it makes no difference.

How do I make sure the translation file is loaded before any HTML rendering takes place?

Comment: no updates on this one? having the same issue

Comment: Nope, sorry. We switched to simply preloading the translations in a JS object.

Comment: Found this working example though: http://jsfiddle.net/SalvadorDali/dLc7x/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with using `i18n-fetch-backend` with the following config:

```
.init({
  ...
  backend: {
    loadPath: "somePatch",
    parse: (data) => {console.log(data)}
  }
})
```

Removing the `parse` attribute solved it for me.